# Define a function replaceCharAtPos which receives two input parameters, a string (orig) and a positive integer number (pos)

Tags: python-3.x

Define a function replaceCharAtPos which receives two input parameters,  a string (orig)  and a positive integer number (pos).

If the number is a position within the string, the function should return a new string. The new string should be the original string except that instead of the original character in that position pos, it should have the position number itself (if the position number has more than 1 digit, the character should be replaced by the digit in the units part of the position number, e.g. 2 if the position number is 12).

If the number pos is not a valid position within the original string orig, the string returned should be exactly  the same as the original string.

For example
 `replaceCharAtPos('abcd',2)` should return 'ab2d'
 `replaceCharAtPos('abcd',10)` should return 'abcd'
 `replaceCharAtPos('abcdefghijklmn',12)` should return 'abcdefghijkl2n'

Answer (score 0):

```
def replaceCharAtPos(orig, pos):
  nstr=list(orig) #Creates a list object using the provided string
  if len(orig)>=pos: #Test to make sure string is long enough
    nstr[pos]='2' #change this to what you want
    finStr=''.join(nstr) #Makes list back to a string
    return finStr #Returns
  else:
    return orig #If string is to short it will return original

print(replaceCharAtPos('abcd', 2)) #returns your example
```

I made this from what I had understood from the question. I had made by changing the string into lists, allowing changing characters. That allows place the new character in the correct location. Then combining it back into a string. Let me know if this helps